# How to make link in header using meteoric

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, meteor-blaze, meteoric

I need to make a link to another page in Meteor using Meteoric package. I'm trying to add it to the right of the header with a button. If I create a button in {{#contentFor "headerButtonRight"}} - it aligns as expected. But if I add a  tag - alignment is no longer applied. I tried putting the element to "headerTitle" and add class "pull-right" but results are the same. Currently my code looks like this:

```
{{#contentFor "headerButtonRight"}}
    <a href="{{pathFor 'drafts.add'}}" class="pull-right"><button class="button button-clear pull-right">{{> ionIcon icon="ios-barcode"}} Scan</button></a>
{{/contentFor}}
```

If this is not the correct way to put a link button to the right of the header - what is?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the button nested inside the link tage try...

```
{{#contentFor "headerButtonRight"}}
<a href="{{pathFor 'drafts.add'}}" class="button button-clear">{{> ionIcon icon="ios-barcode"}} Scan</a>
{{/contentFor}}
```